# Is it possible to have 3 servers communicating to each other all on a single port (say port 48000) using Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server

Similar to how a server can have multiple clients connect to it using a single port, I would like this server to also be able to connect to multiple other servers using this same port without having to have a separate TCP client socket on a different port.

eg. Server 1, 2, and 3 all talk to each other using a single port (say 48000) rather than each hosting a TCP socket on 48000 and also having to create two more TCP client sockets on two extra ports to communicate with the other two servers.

The reason for this is for a distributed application that could in theory scale to more than 65k servers potentially all connected to each other which would cause each server to run out of available ports to create client sockets on.

More specifically, is this possible using Python and the sockets library?

This code isn't literal, just representative of what my program is trying to achieve.

```
    self.tcp_socket.bind(("", 48000))
    # Server thread
    self.tcp_socket.listen()
    client, address = self.tcp_socket.accept()

    # Connecting to other server as client
    self.tcp_socket.connect((192.168.1.10, 48000))
```

When trying to connect to a server using a socket that is already in use as a server (listen, accept) I get the error "[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied".

It seems bound to a single port, my program can only act as a client (connecting to a single server), or as a server (having multiple clients connecting using multithreading) but not both.

In short, I want many servers connecting to each other over TCP using a single port for all communication.

Comment: If you think of established connections as a 5-tuple it may help you better understand the conflicts and how to avoid them. A connection 5-tuple is made up of a protocol (tcp), a local socket (i.e. an IP and port)  and a remote socket. Imagine this server-side: (tcp, 10.10.10.10, 1025, 192.168.1.10, 48000) and for the same connection client-side, imagine this: (tcp, 192.168.1.10, 48000, 10.10.10.10, 1025). As long as a single host doesn't try to create two of the same 5-tuples (ignore server/client semantics) it's fine. (**client-side local ip and port are usually chosen automatically)

Comment: This sounds like an x-y question - what’s the actual problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: @barny My 'solution' in isn't really a solution, I am just adding it in to show an approach I have tried and doesn't work. The problem I am trying to solve is to have multiple servers each on their own IP, hosting a service on a single port which they can receive connections from other servers, but also through this port initiate connections to the other servers. In essence all communication would be done on a single port.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: windows doesn't support multible servers on the same machine(refere to comments)
In your case, you just had to define another socket-variable, eg: "connection", and not use the same variable, which was defined as a server-socket. But you also must define two functions and then run threads over this, otherwise it wont work. For Example:

```
from threading import Thread
def bind():
    tcp_socket.bind(("", 4444))
    # Server thread
    tcp_socket.listen()
    client, address = tcp_socket.accept()

def connect():
   connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   connection.connect((192.168.1.10, 4444))

t1 = Thread(target=bind)
t2 = Thread(target=connect)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

PS: I recommend to use lower port-numbers, because there is a limit.

Comment: The issue with that is that for each server I need to connect to, I would have to create a new client connection using a new port which is not what I want to do. 

I only want to use a single port for all connections from/to all servers. They will each have unique IPs. 

In theory this is possible as what marklap stated, these will all be unique IP/port tuples, just that I want to be able to act as a client from the server socket.

Comment: As fare as I know, windows doesn´t support multiple servers on the same ip and port. Technicly it is possible, but this depens on the os you are working with and in which language. Anyway, this wont work in the way I have shown above.